# How I can display asp.net validationsummary horizontally?

Tags: asp.net, validation, validationsummary

I`m using asp.net validator, and now I need to dispaly validationsummary horizontally, How I can do it?
tx

```
<asp:ValidationSummary ID="ValidationSummary1" runat="server" ValidationGroup="RegCargoMain" DisplayMode="BulletList" />
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do that with some simple CSS. Give the ValidationSummary a class and do some styling.

```
<asp:ValidationSummary ID="ValidationSummary1" runat="server" DisplayMode="BulletList" 
   CssClass="HorizontalSummary" />

<style>
    .HorizontalSummary li {
        float: left;
        margin-left: 40px;
    }
</style>
```